# paypal checkout button get json response in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In the [paypal API reference page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create) it says after creating a payment it will return a response. I would like to use the transaction information after payment is completed, but I'm not sure how to obtain this response json from the basic integration scenario [here](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/button.md). After going through the documentation, I don't see where I can get this response. Am I missing a missing a option here? Thanks in advance.

The following is my code

```
paypal.Button.render({

    // Set your environment

    env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

    // Pass the client ids to use to create your transaction on sandbox and production environments

    client: {
        sandbox:    'removed for security', // from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
        production: 'removed for security'  // from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
    },

    // Pass the payment details for your transaction
    // See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create for the expected json parameters

    payment: function() {
        return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: {
                        total:    total,
                        currency: 'USD'
                    },
                    custom: purchaseOrderNumber
                }
            ]
        });
    },

    // Display a "Pay Now" button rather than a "Continue" button

    commit: true,

    // Pass a function to be called when the customer completes the payment

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        console.log("data", data);
        console.log("actions", actions);
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            console.log('The payment was completed!');

            //use transaction information from json response here
        });
    },

    // Pass a function to be called when the customer cancels the payment

    onCancel: function(data) {
        console.log('The payment was cancelled!');
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

EDIT:

console results for data

```
{

"paymentToken":"EC-8T213183GM917341N",
"payerID":"784ARKSZGWBPG",
"paymentID":"PAY-00M809553A479072XLEBN4RI",
"intent":"sale",
"returnUrl":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/?paymentId=PAY-00M809553A479072XLEBN4RI&token=EC-8T213183GM917341N&PayerID=784ARKSZGWBPG"

}
```

console results for actions

```
{
    "payment":{}
}
//see below for console screenshot
```

[image]

EDIT2:

request to paypal framework and response

[image: request to framework when creating payment]

[image: response when creating payment]

[image: request to framework when executing]

[image: response when executing]

It would appear that The last picture is the response that I actually need. Is there a way to obtain this data from a basic paypal button?

Comment: have you set your paypal dev account to use the sandbox? and to make it clear...you press the paypal checkout button, then you land on paypal and you do all your stuff there and at the end when it redirects you back to your page it doesn't work. Or you event don't get to paypal sandbox?

Comment: Yes I have setup my account to use sandbox and everything is working fine. I don't need to redirect to another page. I just want to use the information from response to do some other stuff, that is all. If there is a variable somewhere that contains the response json that would be great.

Comment: what do you see in `data` and `actions`?

Comment: @Edwin and also to clarify, clicking the paypal checkout button opens a popup that shows in the same page. I think this is because I am using basic integration as seen [here](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/button.md)

Comment: could you post your request to the paypal framework aswell?

Comment: There's a whole lot of them. I'm not sure which one to post. What kind of information would be useful here?

Comment: in the paypal api you have sample requests, one that looks like that from there.

Comment: so actually that should be the return result of the function `payment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a parameter to `actions.payment.execute().then()` to catch the response

```
paypal.Button.render({

    // Set your environment

    env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

    // Pass the client ids to use to create your transaction on sandbox and production environments

    client: {
        sandbox:    'removed for security', // from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
        production: 'removed for security'  // from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
    },

    // Pass the payment details for your transaction
    // See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create for the expected json parameters

    payment: function() {
        return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: {
                        total:    total,
                        currency: 'USD'
                    },
                    custom: purchaseOrderNumber
                }
            ]
        });
    },

    // Display a "Pay Now" button rather than a "Continue" button

    commit: true,

    // Pass a function to be called when the customer completes the payment

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

        return actions.payment.execute().then(function(param) {
            console.log('The payment was completed!');

            //param is the json response
        });
    },

    // Pass a function to be called when the customer cancels the payment

    onCancel: function(data) {
        console.log('The payment was cancelled!');
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

Answer (score 1):

The setup seems all good, all you need now is to decide what and how you want to handle your response.

In the `onAuthorize` function you can do something like ([github paypal checkout button](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/button.md#advanced-integration)) this for all of your aproved sales (check for `data.status` to be `approved` (credit card) or `created` (for payment with paypal), then you should have a `data.payer` with all the info):

```
jQuery.post('/my-api/execute-payment', { paymentID: data.paymentID, payerID: data.payerID });
            .done(function(data) { /* Go to a success page */ })
            .fail(function(err)  { /* Go to an error page  */  });
```

or use directly the `data` json object in the function.

Comment: I finally figured it out! If a parameter is passed to `actions.payment.execute().then(function(response){})` that will be the response. I'm going to post the whole code and mark that as the solution, but Edwin thank you very much for the input! Also, I think I would create a PR on github to make this clear for other people.